# how to short file path in linux shell script output

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i am taking output of below shell script as an email.
in which file name time size are there.

pint file name i am getting whole directory which is too long.

some how is it possible to keep only last one or two directory name and file name. ?

```
#!/bin/bash

monitor_dir=/path/to/dir
email=me@me.com

files=$(find "$monitor_dir" -maxdepth 1 | sort)
IFS=$'\n'

while true
do
  sleep 5s

  newfiles=$(find "$monitor_dir" -maxdepth 1 | sort)
  added=$(comm -13 <(echo "$files") <(echo "$newfiles"))

  [ "$added" != "" ] &&
    find $added -maxdepth 1 -printf '%Tc\t%s\t%p\n' |
    mail -s "incoming" "$email"

  files="$newfiles"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

This prints the last two directories in the path plus the file name:

```
echo "/the/long/path/to/your/file" | awk -F/ '{printf "/";for (i=NF-2;i<=NF;i++){printf $i"/"}}'
```

To control how many you get modify the loop variable initializer (i.e. NF-2).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this

```
find $added -maxdepth 1 -printf '%Tc\t%s\t%p\n' |
  awk '{printf "%s/%s\n", $(NF-1), $NF}' FS=/
```